# i'm tring to locate android studio SDK (Error Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Android studio
Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
.PHONY: update_sdk_dir

update_sdk_dir: force_update
    @echo "sdk.dir=/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk" > local.properties

force_update:
    @touch force_update


Error: mac@macs-MacBook-Pro SocWebCash % make update_sdk_dir
Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

i have tried this method but not working.

I'm trying to update this using this command

make update_sdk_dir